# New Item losing meta data when saved

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a SharePoint list. This list has fields: field1; field2 and field3. When I add a new item; in the edit form I add all the values for field1; field2 and field3.

But when I save the item; field2 and field3 are missing the metadata I just added. I have to switch to the datagrid view for the list and add the metadata.

Any suggestions on why the fields are losing the metadata when saved.

Thanks

Comment: Are there any event receivers running that might be erasing the values from the 2 fields? Do you have any custom javascript on your list edit form that could be removing the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you customized form with InfoPath?

If yes, you can use the default form.

Navigate to list settings->Form settings->choose "use the default SharePoint form":

[image]

Make sure there is no custom code in default form.

Make sure there is no workflow set values for the fields.